# Rotating and Scaling with React-Motion

Tags: css, reactjs, react-motion

Struggling to get my head round '**rotating**' and '**scaling**' in React Motion v4 and cant seem to find much about how to do it online. Its easy to change a simple css property along with a simple state change like below:

```
<Motion 
 defaultStyle={{opacity: 0}}
 style={{opacity: spring(this.state.isActive ? 1 : 0, {stiffness: 200, damping: 12})}}>
 {style => 
  <div style={{opacity: style.opacity}} className="action-panel">
   <div id="action-content" className="action-panel-content"></div>
  </div>
 }                            
</Motion>
```

However how do i do the above with more complex css properties such as '**transform: rotate(90deg)**' for example ?

Finally if i want to have more complex state logic, such as animation that occurs on rollover and rollout and if various states are true or false where's best to do that ? Prior to using React Motion I was updating the inline styles of the element based on its state and some conditionals, I'm not really sure how to do this now just using React Motion. Your thoughts would be welcomed! :D

t xx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `rotate` & `scale` you can use [**tagged template literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) `${ expresion }`.

let me show you

```js
<Motion
  defaultStyle={{ rotate: 0, scale: 1}}
  style={{ rotate: spring(180), scale: spring(3)}}
>

  {style => 
    (
      <div style={{ 
       transform: `rotate( ${style.rotate}deg )`,
       transform: `scale( ${style.scale}, ${style.scale} )`
     }}> </div>    
    )
  }

</Motion>
```

**notice the use of backticks**

For interactive animation, React is very good in accessing the DOM and uses SyntheticEvents which includes [**Mouse Events**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events).

`onClick onContextMenu onDoubleClick onDrag onDragEnd onDragEnter 
 onDragExit onDragLeave onDragOver onDragStart onDrop onMouseDown 
 onMouseEnter onMouseLeave onMouseMove onMouseOut onMouseOver onMouseUp`

here's a *mouse hover* example using `setState`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Motion, spring } from 'react-motion'

class App extends Component { 
  state = {
   rotate: 0
  }
  enter(){
    this.setState({rotate: 180})
  }
  leave(){
    this.setState({rotate: 0})
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <Motion
        defaultStyle={{ rotate: 0}}
        style={{ rotate: spring(this.state.rotate)}}
      >

       {style => 
         (
           <div 
             style={{ 
               transform: `rotate( ${style.rotate}deg )`,
             }}
             onMouseEnter={this.enter.bind(this)}
             onMouseLeave={this.leave.bind(this)}
           > </div>    
         )
        }

      </Motion>
     )
  }
}
export default App
```

now this won't show anything since there is no *pre-defined* dimensions of the `div`. to do this, let's declare `styles` object.

below the `import` lines

```js
const styles = {
  div: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'papayawhip'
  }
}
```

then you can use it like so:

```js
style={ Object.assign( {},
  styles.div,
  { 
    transform: `rotate( ${style.rotate}deg )`,
    // more styles here...
  })
}
```

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).

Comment: thank you for removing it. i actually went back to edit my answer.